# How to count the number of review comments from a specific author in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, openoffice, docx

I have a large MS Word document with a high number of review comments (track changes feature). I'd now like to get a list of authors and the number of review comments. The number of authors is not too long, so if I can get the information for one author at a time, that's fine.

I'm using Word 2013. If it's possible to find out in OpenOffice / LibreOffice or any other tool, that's also fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I managed to get accurate results like this:

1. Go to the `Review` ribbon
2. In the `Tracking` section, open the dropdown `Show markup`
3. Deselect everything except comments
4. Open dropdown `Show markup` again
5. Under `Specific people`, mark only one person
6. Click on `Reviewing Pane`

In the reviewing pane, it now shows `xx Revisions`. As far as I could see, these are all comments now, so we have the number of comments for one author.

From now on it is much easier to do the same for other authors, because you just need to change the person under `Specific people`.

Answer (score 0):

This method may look cumbersome but it can be useful in certain situations:

If you save the document as .txt it will contain the main text of the document at first, and the comment list at the end, in this format:

```
[MG1]The whole table needs to be reviewed and updated.
[MG2]Remove section 2.2.4
[MG3]Insert correct reference.
...
```

You can then filter by the commenter's initials i.e. `[MG` and count the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Put document to :
Print preview
in Settings select print markup
scroll to bottom and you will see initials with #'s

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).